# Which PhD position I should accept?

Tags: publications, postdocs, job, industry, ranking

I am finishing my master's degree and got 2 PhD offers, one of them in ivy league school but in a lab doing applied science with no molecular biology and the second in a university ranked 120 in the US but the lab have a well established molecular techniques and bio informatics which I am interested to learn!
My preference is going to the lower rank university because of the kind of science, the techniques I will learn and also I will be more intensively included in paper and grant writing!

I am afraid that a PhD from such university will limit my chances in getting academia or industry jobs!

Which offer I should pick?

Comment: A decade on, is the duplicate definitive? Interestingly, it appears so. There are nuances in current dispensation and personal goals. My comments will simply be, which you've indicated yourself, how are these to your goals ...  *the kind of science, the techniques I will learn and also I will be more intensively included in paper and grant writing!*